# Factorial-like function that behaves like $ 1\times \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt[3]{3} \times \dots \times \sqrt[n-1]{n-1} \times \sqrt[n]{n} $?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, interpolation

The Barnes G-function is a generalization of the factorial funcion which grows a lot faster.  The factorial:

$$ n! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \dots \times (n-1) \times  n  $$

Then it is possible to write a [super-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Superfactorial):

$$ n!! = 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times \dots \times (n-1)! \times  n!
= 1^n \times 2^{n-1} \times \dots \times (n-1)^2 \times n^1  $$

For a given combinatorics function $f(n)$ we can try to extend to $f(x)$ with $n < x < n+1$.  The super-factorial can be continued to the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

How can I get a function that behaves like the product of successive $n$-th roots?

$$ f(n) =  1\times \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt[3]{3} \times \dots \times \sqrt[n-1]{n-1} \times \sqrt[n]{n} $$

I tried looking amongst the [multiple gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_gamma_function) but there is no *negative* multiple Gamma functions... now what?

Comment: In my experience, $n!!$ is used to refer to the [semifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: @cactus314 A feedback concerning my answer below would be great.

Answer (score 6):

One may first observe that
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)&=1\times \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt[3]{3} \times \dots \times \sqrt[n-1]{n-1} \times \sqrt[n]{n}
\\&=\prod_{k=1}^n k^{\large \frac1k}
\\&=e^{ \sum_{k=1}^n\!\frac{\ln k}k}.
\end{align}
$$ We are then led to consider $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln k}k$.

One may recall the [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) and the [generalized Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Generalized_Stieltjes_constants),
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma_1=&\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\ln k}k- \int_{1}^N \frac{\ln x}x\:dx\right)
\\\gamma_1(a)=&\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{\ln (k+a)}{k+a}-\int_{0}^N \frac{\ln (x+a)}{x+a}\:dx\right),\quad  a>0,
\end{align}
$$  then one may observe that, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln k}k= \lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\ln k}k- \frac{\ln^2 N}2\right)-\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\ln (k+n)}{k+n}- \frac{\ln^2 (N+n)}2\right)
$$ giving

> $$
> 1\times \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt[3]{3} \times \dots \times \sqrt[n-1]{n-1} \times \sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\Large\gamma_1-\gamma_1(n+1)}, \qquad n\ge1.
> $$

Some results on the Stieltjes constants : [Coffey (2005)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0506061.pdf), [Adell (2010)](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/467/2128/954), [Fekih-Ahmed (2014)](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/1026562/filename/Fekihahmed_Stieltes_asymptotics_v0.1.pdf), [Paris (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03948v2.pdf).